# How execute perl one-liner from perl script (properly escaped)

Tags: linux, centos, bash, perl, regex

I have a perl script from within which I need to execute a simple perl one-liner on a remote host:

```
ssh 192.168.1.1 "perl -pi.bup -e 's/^(\s+?kernel)(.*)(?<!audit=1)$/$1$2 audit=1/' /etc/grub.conf"
```

This simply adds "`audit=1`" to the end of each kernel line in `/etc/grub.conf` if it does not already exist.

The one-liner works just fine when run directly on the host, but not when executed via ssh from within another perl script.  I have tried to escape all dollar signs with one or more backslashes and I have also tried to escape the backslash in "`\s`", but nothing I do seems to work.

Note I do not want to copy a script to the remote host and then execute it - I would like to do it using the ssh command directly.

**How to properly escape this so that it works?**

*-- Update 9/9/2015 to show exactly what I am doing in the perl script:*

```
sub SomeMethod
{
   &RunCommand($host, "perl -pi.bup -e \'s/^(\s+?kernel)(.*)(?<!audit=1)\$/\$1\$2 audit=1/\' /etc/grub.conf");
}

sub RunCommand
{
    my ($server, $command) = @_;
    my $commandOutput = "";

    if ($server ne "")
    {
        $command = "ssh $server \"$command\"";
    }

    $commandOutput = `$command`; 
    print $commandOutput;

    if (($? >> 8) != 0)
    {
        &LogMessage ("$command failed:\n\n$commandOutput");
        return $commandOutput;
    }
    return $commandOutput;
}
```

-- Update #2, using `system` instead of back-ticks:

```
system 'ssh', $host, 'perl', '-pi.bup', '-e', 's/^(\s+?kernel)(.*)(?<!audit=1)$/$1$2 audit=1/', '/etc/grub.conf';
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `perl -pi.bup -e s/^(\s+?kernel)(.*)(?<!audit=1)$/$1$2 audit=1/ /etc/grub.conf'
```

**Ok, I can use system here, but how to properly escape it??**

Comment: @c4f4t0r sed vs. perl is probably not the issue here - it is more a matter of properly escaping the needed characters.  But if you can provide a sed command that will work when executed via ssh (as in my post) from within a perl script, I will happily use that instead.

Comment: Show exactly what you're doing in the perl script.

Comment: @glenn Ok, code added to post.

Comment: In my previous an missed one \

Comment: Less related to your question, you may also want to look into the use of grubby, if that is an option for you.  You may find it easier to add/remove/change grub options.  Sorry, I know that isn't related to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're editing the remote file in place, you don't need to capture the output, so `system` would be preferable than using backticks:

```
system 'ssh', '192.168.1.1', 'perl', '-pi.bup', '-e', 's/^(\s+?kernel)(.*)(?<!audit=1)$/$1$2 audit=1/', '/etc/grub.conf';
```

Note that you don't have to pass the remote command as a single parameter to ssh. That helps the quoting a bit. If you really want to, you can:

```
system 'ssh', '192.168.1.1', q{perl -pi.bup -e 's/^(\s+?kernel)(.*)(?<!audit=1)$/$1$2 audit=1/' /etc/grub.conf};
```

Using the `q{}` operator to allow the perl one-liner to use single quotes.

---

I would do this, actually:

```
use Try::Tiny;
use IPC::System::Simple qw{capture};

sub SomeMethod
{
    my $output = RemoteCommand(
                    $host, 
                    q{perl -pi.bup -e 's/^(\s+?kernel)(.*)(?<!audit=1)$/$1$2 audit=1/' /etc/grub.conf}
                );
}

sub RemoteCommand
{
    my ($server, $command) = @_;
    my $output;

    try {
        $output = capture('ssh', $server, $command);
    }
    catch {
        LogMessage("command failed: ($command) : $_");
        $output = $_;
    };

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: The RunCommand method is used by a large number of methods and I would like to not modify it, if possible (not to break other functionality).  I was hoping for some guidance on how to escape the command in my original post.

Comment: Since backticks execute your command with `sh -c 'your command'`, it will be very difficult to get the escaping right. I'd not bother. Make your implementation more robust.

Comment: Ok, I tried using "system" instead - please see my edit for the result.  Still needs some escaping and I still have a hard time making it work...

Comment: [`system` is a perl function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), not a shell command.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following simple command and it works

```
ssh localhost "sed -i.bck '/[^audit]/{s/\(^\s\+kernel.*\)/\1 audit=1/g}' /boot/grub/menu.lst"
```

Isn't about `sed vs perl`, but using the previous command is more clear to archive what you want.

Comment: that almost works (provided that you use "\\1" instead of "\1") directly from bash.  But it is only supposed to append "audit=1" if it is not already there - as it is now it appends it always.  Also, it is only supposed to affect lines that start with the word kernel (preceeding spaces ok).  I tried this, but it did not update the file: ssh localhost "sed -i.bck 's/\^(\s\+kernel.*\)\(?<!audit=1\)\$/\\1 audit=1/g' /etc/grub.conf ; cat /etc/grub.conf"

Comment: @Zek I updated my sed command, Now the command works only when the line kernel doesn't have audit key word

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working.

From bash directly:

```
echo 's/^(\s+?kernel)(.*)(?<!audit=1)$/$1$2 audit=1/' | ssh 192.168.1.1 "perl -pi.bup - /etc/grub.conf"
```

From perl script:

```
my $command = "echo 's/^(\\s+?kernel)(.*)(?<!audit=1)\$/\$1\$2 audit=1/' | ssh $_wsAddress 'perl -pi.bup - /etc/grub.conf' ";
&RunCommand("", $command);
```